# PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "vouchers.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Im trying to group voucher by monthly table.

In Voucher model

```
def self.total_grouped_by_day(start)
    vouchers = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
    vouchers = vouchers.group("date(created_at)")
    vouchers = vouchers.select("created_at, sum(harga) as total_price")
    vouchers.group_by { |v| v.created_at.to_date }
end
```

In Voucher helper

```
module VouchersHelper
    def orders_chart_data
        orders_by_day = Voucher.total_grouped_by_day(1.month.ago)
        (1.month.ago.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
            {
                created_at: date,
                price: orders_by_day[date].first.try(:total_price) || 0
            }
        end
    end
end
```

But i got this error =

**"PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "vouchers.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"**

How to fix this? Thank you

Comment: Which database are you using now

Comment: @Jegan Postgresql sir..

Comment: Could you post the queries when calling the method

Comment: <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "orders_chart", data: {orders: orders_chart_data} %>

Comment: Not this one.Please call orders_chart_data in rails console..please copy the output and paste it here.

Comment: Voucher.group("date(created_at)").select("created_at, sum(price) as total_price").first

Comment: When you call this on rails console what all are the database(sql) queries are fired